# SharePoint 2013 is keep prompting

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, authentication, credentials

SharePoint 2013 is keep on prompting, I see that user credentials is not being passed while trying to access an image. However, the page itself is getting loaded without any issues.

Tried on all the browsers - IE, EDGE, Chrome.

> 20:00:22 xx.xx.xx.xx GET  /Images1/Smart+Choices+270x356.jpg - 80 -
>   xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/70.0.3538.67+Safari/537.36
>   http://demo.com /pages/default.aspx 401 0 0 15
>
> 20:00:22 xx.xx.xx.xx GET  /Images1/Smart+Choices+270x356.jpg - 80 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/70.0.3538.67+Safari/537.36
>   http://demo.com /pages/default.aspx 401 1 2148074254 0
>
> 20:00:22 xx.xx.xx.xx GET  /Images1/Smart+Choices+270x356.jpg - 80 - xx.xx.xx.xx
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/70.0.3538.67+Safari/537.36
>   http://demo.com /pages/default.aspx 401 1 2148074252 202

**Edit:**
User is able to access the image when it is accessed directly on another new tab. Somehow browser does not send the credentials when the image is accessed from the page.

Comment: How are you accessing the image on the page? and where are the images stored?

Comment: Is the image in mysite? or on another site collection?

Answer (score 5):

**Make sure that**

- The image is not checked-out, try to upload it again as a new version and check it in.
- The library/folder that holds the image doesn't have a unique permission.
- The image itself doesn't have a unique permission.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at:

- The site and sub-sites have been added to the local intranet zone e.g. *.domain.co.uk
- That the User Authentication Log On has been set to automatically login on intranet zones.

We currently use this setup to handle our third party apps.